# Is it possible to integrate an opening book and/or endgame tablebase into a chess engine? If so, how?

Tags: engines

I'm currently attempting to program a chess engine for a club project; one where many different people could create different engines and they could play a tournament or something of that nature. As such, I'm not sure if it's appropriate for me to rely on a GUI like Arena to provide opening/endgame database support.

Is there a good way to integrate such databases into the engine itself? I am using UCI on Java to program the engine.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to integrate an opening book and/or endgame tablebase. Unfortunately there is no Java solutions, because chess engine programming is dominated by C/C++. Maybe you want to switch to C/C++? Your life will be easier.

**Opening book**

PolyGlot book (http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/details1/PolyGlot.html)

**Tablebase**

Syzygy tablebase (this [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9960/what-is-syzygy-tablebases) has the details)

**My recommendation**

Unless you're an expert in programming, I don't think it's a good idea to work on Polyglot and Syzygy yourself. They're not written for beginners. GUI like Arena would be a better idea.